# Package cannot be (re-)installed or uninstalled

Tags: adb, apk, side-loading

My device is a non-rooted device. I was trying to install SDMove.apk (sideload) from my ICS tablet.

Adb reported:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

When I issue uninstall command, it reports Failure too.

When I try to browse all installed apps on phone (via launcher or via Settings>App menu) the application "SDMove" does not show up.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could it be the app is already (pre-)installed as a system package? That would be the easiest explanation: A package with that name already exists (so it cannot be installed) -- but being a system packe, you cannot uninstall it. If you know the *package name* (something like `com.foobar.app`), try an `adb shell "ls /system/app/com.foobar.app"` to check if it's there (hopefully this doesn't require root ;)

Comment: @Izzy, thanks, but I confirm in negative. It is certainly not a system app. Continue to be stumped.

Comment: Include me with your confusion -- the above was the only reason I can think of at the moment, sorry.